# DrawerLayout's background make dimmer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drawerlayout

I'd like to know how to make the drawer background to be come dimmer when the drawer is open. I have a transparent Drawer Menu(listView). When the drawer is opened, and for example I have a listview also under a one Menu, the two listviews overlaps. Android has a default dimming of the screen, but I'd like it to be even darker.

Android uses this kind of format: `Color.DKGRAY`

**Update:**

```
public void setScrimColor (int color)
Set a color to use for the scrim that obscures primary content while a drawer is open.

Parameters
color   Color to use in 0xAARRGGBB format.


mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED), GravityCompat.START);
or
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `setScrimColor(int color)` method. As default color is used `0x99000000`. If you want to use color specified in resources you can call:

`setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color))`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a custom class that extends DrawerLayout.
Then you can override some methods such as onDrawerOpen() etc.

In there you can set the background of the main layout.
If you're interested in the implementation of DrawerLayout, check it on Grepcode [here](http://www.grepcode.com)

Answer (score 1):

use DrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(Drawable, int)

Comment: what kind of drawableshould I put in it sir? also the int?

Comment: what kind of Drawable did you try? int is Gravity.*

Comment: I tried using the `setDrawerShadow` and it did not resolve my concern. It only occupies few area in the screen. It's like the border to the right of the menu

Comment: what Drawable did you use?

Comment: drawer_shadow.9.png  http://oi44.tinypic.com/10e0ak8.jpg  `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);`

Comment: I added image above. pls see

Comment: the color you have chosen is not my favourite one but its just my taste